# How to read and write data to open socket?

Tags: version-10, undocumented, streams

I am trying to open connection with socket. I am using this:

```
Needs["SocketLink`"];
port = 8888;
socket = CreateServerSocket[port];
{in, out} = OpenSocketStreams[socket];
```

If I am writing to output stream then the message is printed:

```
BynaryWrite[out, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
```

> BinaryWrite::errfile: "Could not access file "File write failed"".

Also, If I am trying to read data from input stream then the  mathematica kernel stops.

How can I read and write data to streams, but not use the function *CreateAsynchronousServer*?. How can I wait for a request to the server? I want to use for solving this problem *ScheduledTasks*.

I want to create a simple http-server. I know how create a server using *CreateAsynchronousServer*. For example:

```
CreateAsynchronousServer[CreateServerSocket[8888], Handler]

Handler[{in_InputStream, out_OutputStream}] :=
    Module[{responsestring = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\n\r\ntest"},
        While[True, TimeConstrained[BinaryRead[in], 0.01, (Close[in]; Break[])]];
        BinaryWrite[out, ToCharacterCode[responsestring]];
        Close[out];
    ];
```

Result is a server that is handles the request from http://localhost:8888 using the function *Handler*. Within handler I can read and write data to output stream related with a socket. But I don't know how to do it without using CreateAsynchronousServer.

Comment: Can you discuss a bit abut what you want to do with this functionality?

Comment: Yes! I updated my question.